# progressbar in openGL android

Tags: android, opengl-es, progress-bar

I am working to draw progressbar using OpenGL in Android. Is there someone who can suggest. I have been able to draw static images for the bars using OpenGL. I want to fill the color on the bar depending upon the progress.

What I need is how to resize the vertices buffer for the progress? I am trying to take two different vertex buffers. one for drawing the background and other for the progress. Now I want to fill color in the progress buffer and its length should depend on the data recieved.

Comment: @user8709 thanks for the reply. Any will do? Have tried my lots of hands to it but still unsuccessful...